Angular 19 Material themes - system variables
Angular 19 has changed the syntax and underlying scss files.
I am trying to access the systems variables https://material.angular.io/guide/system-variables defined as part of angular 19 but unable to use them. Any idea on how to get the primary color using these variables ?
    @include mat.theme((
      color: (
        primary: mat.$red-palette,
        tertiary: mat.$green-palette,
        theme-type: light,
        use-system-variables: true
      ),
      typography: Roboto,
      density: 0
    ));
   
    $primary: var(--mat-sys-primary);
    
    @debug "primary: #{$primary}";
    

}

Output isnt giving me the color (hex code)
src/styles/theme.scss:32 DEBUG: primary: var(--mat-sys-primary)


@maxkart issue not reproducible stackblitz

@NarenMurali thanks .. i have update the stackblitz to reflect the scenario and issue which i am facing .. essentially trying to store the primary color in a colors.scss file which i am importing in various components

@JamesP - this is more specific to the changes introduced by Angular 19

@NarenMurali .. thanks i have managed to make it work . the issue seems to be my project setup. appreciate your help.

According to the docs, you must use mat.theme-overrides:

Overrides
The mat.theme-overrides mixin can be included to emit different definitions for the system variables and override the definitions emitted from mat.theme.
This example container has several system variables overridden by including the following Sass code:

  @include mat.theme-overrides((
    primary: #ebdcff,
    on-primary: #230f46,
    body-medium: 500 1.15rem/1.3rem Arial,
    corner-large: 32px,
    level3: 0 4px 6px 1px var(--mat-sys-surface-dim),
  ));


Thanks .. but the this isnt about the overrides the issue is more around reading and primary color and using it the components scss files.. i have update the https://stackblitz.com/edit/dt5xx7dv-zeixho57?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fcolors.scss,src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.css,angular.json,src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.html
